# Setting pdf path in FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am trying to set the *pdf path* from

```
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile("doc.pdf");
```

(**doc.pdf** is present in the same directory as the **php script**)

to a pdf that is uploaded on some other server (http://www.example.com/xyz.pdf)

I tried this : `$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile("http://www.example.com/xyz.pdf");` but it didn't work.

I am new to programming. Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## FPDI 1.x

FPDI uses filesystem functions to navigate through the PDF document (e.g. [fseek()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php)). This requires that the stream that is opened is seekable which isn't the case if an http wrapper is used. You will need a local copy of the document or implement an individual stream wrapper that would allow you to read from e.g. [a variable](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/miscellaneous/using-a-pdf-from-a-php-variable-instead-of-a-file/#question-192).

## FPDI 2.x

In FPDI 2 you don't need to use a stream wrapper anymore but you can read from a variable by using an instance of the `StreamReader` class, which can be created and passed like this:

```
// use a resource
$fh = fopen('a/path/to/a.pdf', 'rb');
$pdf->setSourceFile(new StreamReader($fh));
// same as
$pdf->setSourceFile($fh);
// don't forget to call fclose($fh);

// use a path
$path = 'a/path/to/a.pdf';
$pdf->setSourceFile(StreamReader::createByFile($path));
// same as
$pdf->setSourceFile($path);

// use a string
$pdfString = '%%PDF-1.4...';
$pdf->setSourceFile(StreamReader::createByString($pdfString));
```

Comment: Can I put the local copy of the document into some other directory. E.g FPDF script is present in the root directory of my server and the document is present in /uploads directory. What would be the code for setting it as path?

Comment: `$pdf->setSourceFile("uploads/name.pdf");` ?